# Passing variable into sshpass command inside a script for loop

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to create a script (test.sh) that logs on to another server and checks the disk usage of some different folders:

test.sh:

```
DIRS="dir_A dir_B dir_C"

for DIR in $DIRS
do
  sshpass -p user_password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user_name@host 'cd /opt/app/$DIR;SIZE=$(du -s);echo "YVALUE="$SIZE > ../size_$DIR.txt'
done
```

However, the variable DIR never gets passed to the script. It is empty when I run the script. I have tried using {} around $DIR but still no success. What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, use double-quotes instead of single-quotes. You can still concatenate with single quotes if necessary:

```
sshpass -p user_password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user_name@host 'cd /opt/app/'"$DIR"';SIZE=$(du -s);echo "YVALUE="$SIZE > ../size_'"$DIR".txt
```

I just noticed something: `du -s` produces an output of two columns so probably it's not being used the proper way yet. Perhaps something like `SIZE=${SIZE%$'\t'*}` is still needed.

Another way is to send the directory by input and let the other end read it:

```
sshpass -p user_password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user_name@host 'read -r DIR; cd "/opt/app/$DIR"; SIZE=$(du -s); echo "YVALUE=$SIZE" > "../size_$DIR.txt"' <<< "$DIR"
```

This would be helpful if directories contain spaces or characters that may cause syntax errors. Using an array is also recommended for it:

```
DIRS=('DIR 1' 'DIR 2' 'DIR 3')
for DIR in "${DIRS[@]}"; do
    sshpass ...
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping a string in single quotes (`'`) will stop any bash expansion taking place, you will need to use double quotes for $DIR to be evaluated, escaping any double quotes within the string that you want to send over SSH:

```
  sshpass -p user_password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user_name@host "cd /opt/app/$DIR;SIZE=\$(du -s);echo \"YVALUE\"=$SIZE > ../size_$DIR.txt"
```

Comment: I would assume that the dollar in `$(du -s)` should also be escaped, otherwise he will be getting the local path size. Konsolebox's answer is better in my opinion anyway though, as it is less error prone.