# Passing a variable in a bash script to sshpass

Tags: bash, sshpass

I am trying to pass a variable in a bash script to sshpass. Here is my code for reference:

```
NAME="HARRY"
sshpass -p passwd ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q ipaddress 'bash -s' << 'EOF'
   echo $NAME
EOF
```

How can I pass the variable in a bash script to sshpass? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variable into sshpass command inside a script for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866413/passing-variable-into-sshpass-command-inside-a-script-for-loop)

Comment: Public-key authentication would let you get rid of `sshpass`, making your script much simpler.

Comment: Agreed, sshpass isn't the most secure way. Also, if you repeat ssh conntections to the same server, consider adding a controlmaster with ssh option `-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=yes -o ControlPath=/var/run/ctrlm.%r@%h` so you keep a persistent ssh connection for some time. This way next time you launch ssh, it keeps the already open connection from last time. By default, controlmasters are open 1H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is using env just before running bash

```
NAME="HARRY"
sshpass -p passwd ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q ipaddress env NAME="$NAME" 'bash -s' << 'EOF'
   echo $NAME
EOF
```

You can pass multiple variables with multiple env statements like

```
export NAME="HARRY"
export SOMEVAR="hello"
sshpass -p passwd ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q ipaddress env NAME="$NAME" env SOMEVAR="$SOMEVAR" 'bash -s' << 'EOF'
   echo $NAME
EOF
```

Be aware that your variables might be interpreted when passing them. You can avoid that by changing `env NAME="$NAME"` to uninterpreted version `env NAME="'$NAME'"`

Comment: This can cause its own problems, because now `ssh` has to combine `env` and all its arguments into a single string.

Comment: Indeed, best solution I found so far is singlequoting the variable in doublequotes to avoid unwanted interpetation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a dollarsign in front of the variable name, as in this example:

```
Linux Prompt>cat test.txt
<here you see file content>
Linux Prompt>filename=test.txt
Linux Prompt>cat $filename
<here you see file content>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put it after the `-p` option:

```
password=YourPassword
sshpass -p "$password" ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q ipaddress 'bash -s' <<EOF
    echo "$NAME"
EOF
```